# Problemas con openpyxl en python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Bueno mi problema seria que cuando solicito el dato de una celda que contiene una formula en vez de devolverme el resultado de esta formula me devuelve la formula. Por ejemplo en caso de que una celda contenga =SUM(25+25) en lugar de devolverme el resultado osea 50 me devuelve la mismo operacion =SUM(25+25)
Aqui pongo la parte del codigo donde creo debe estar el erro.

```
mes= self.wb[self.mes_de_planilla.get()]
id= []
    
    for row in range(3, mes.max_row):
        _row= [row,]
        for col in mes.iter_cols(1, mes.max_column):
            _row.append(col[row].value)
        id.append(_row)

    id= np.array(id)
    tabla= np.array([[StringVar, StringVar, StringVar, StringVar]])

    for x in id:
        tabla= np.insert(tabla, 0, [[x[2], x[3], x[5], x[8]]], axis= 0)
    print(tabla)
    for y in tabla:
        if(y[0] == None):
            pass
        if(y[0] != None):
            table.insert("", END, text= y[0], values=(y[1], y[2], y[3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Disculpen las molestias justo hice la pregunta y encontre la solucion. Para el que tenga el mismo problema lo que debe hacer es agregar data_only= True

```
self.wb= xl.load_workbook('pruebas.xlsx', data_only= True)
```